# It is possible to complete the October Frontier challenge in 48 days without cheating?

Tags: the-colonists

Today, DragonZH posted a record time of 1 month, 19 days for the October frontier challenge to get 1000 pumpkins in storage.

Knowing that a month is 28 days, and rounding the last day up gives a total of 48 days.
On paper, a farm generates 2 pumpkins per day, so an average of 20 fully productive farms would be needed.

The fastest 2 workshop solution I can think of to get off the starting area is 25 days long on paper. 3 workshops does not improve this.

```
Workshop building #1 (1 day)
Scaffolding1 (3 days)
Construction 1 (6 days)
Boatyard (2 days)
Clipper (8 days)
Harbor#2 (2 days)
Scouting Tower (3 days)
```

With the following made in parallel with the above: Workshop building #2, Stonemasonry, Boat building, Harbor #1

Given this, I think that escaping the starting area by boat must be slower than just staying put and growing pumpkins right there.

Fully uncovering the starting area with watch towers can be done in 3 batches of watch towers, constructing in a total of 9 days. Considering that energy production and lumberjack construction needs to happen to support the tower batches, it's closer to 15 days of dramatically less than 20 farms. That leaves 33 days for pumpkin production, requiring close to 30 fully productive pumpkin farms.

There is no way to place 30 fully productive pumpkin farms on the starting area, there's just not enough green area to do it.

So what am I missing?

Here's my 3 month 10 day layout with 17 fully productive pumpkin farms. [image: 17 pumpkin farms]